# segue not working at Login screen to update profile in swift

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase

I'm using Swift2, and logging in using Facebook in my app ( with Firebase as the backend). At the Log In screen , once the user selects FB to log in I want to update the user profile with some additional information and store it in Firebase. But the segue to the controller that updates some info. never shows up. The logs tell me that the facebook account info is retrieved correctly but this segue

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("completeProfile", sender: nil)
```

never works. I have the correct identifier set on the segue.

```
    @IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    AppUtility.loginWithFacebook { (success) in

        if success {
            AppUtility.getUserData({ (success) in
                if success {
                    ApplicationDelegate.showTabBarController()
                }
                else {
                    print ("Attempting FB Login - 5 ")
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("completeProfile", sender: nil)
                    print ("Attempting FB Login - 6 ")

                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly this gets the segue to show:

```
@IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    AppUtility.loginWithFacebook { (success) in
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("completeProfile", sender: nil)

        if success {
            AppUtility.getUserData({ (success) in
                if success {
                    ApplicationDelegate.showTabBarController()
                }
                else {
                    print ("Attempting FB Login - 5 ")
                    print ("Attempting FB Login - 6 ")

                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add, I also have this in my code:
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put it in the success case, like this:

```
@IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
AppUtility.loginWithFacebook { (success) in

    if success {
        AppUtility.getUserData({ (success) in
            if success {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("completeProfile", sender: nil)

ApplicationDelegate.showTabBarController()
            }
            else {
                print ("Attempting FB Login - 5 ")

                print ("Attempting FB Login - 6 ")

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Yet I'm not sure if you want the showTabBarController in the same block.